# Why was Kryten asked to check his chair?

Tags: red-dwarf

In series 8, episode 1 of Red Dwarf, *Back in the Red, pt. 1* the counsellor is evaluating Kryten and keeps asking him if his seat is screwed down. I have no idea why.

> COUNSELLOR
>   Right! I *was* alive, died, and then started living again..?
>
> KRYTEN
>   You have been most fortunate, sir!
>
> [The COUNSELLOR laughs along with the percieved joke, obviously
>   uncomfortable ]
>
> COUNSELLOR
>   I have, haven't I? Golly! Your chair is screwed down, isn't it, Kryten?
>
> [KRYTEN dutifully checks, puzzled, and nods confirmation]

Taken from [this](http://www.cervenytrpaslik.cz/scenare/EN-45-8_Back_in_the_Red_I.htm) website.

Why does the counsellor (repeatedly) ask whether the seat is screwed down?

Comment: Isn't this a Blade Runner joke?

Answer (score 8):

My take on it was that the Counsellor was concerned that Kryten was displaying some quite bizarre and truly irrational behaviours. After speaking to him for just a few seconds, he formed the conclusion that the *most likely* outcome of the meeting is that he would be recommending that Kryten be...

> Restored to Factory Settings

...which is essentially a death-sentence for a droid that has developed sentience.

As his behaviour becomes more and more irrational and the interview comes to a head, he asks him again a couple of times to check the chair because he's worried that Kryten (an insane android who's just about to be told that he's going to be mind-wiped) **will use it to beat him to death.**

Comment: Oh. That's a disappointing punchline...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - That's a pretty fair description of the entire season.

Comment: I really liked that season.  It may have been helped that it was the first one I watched.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Red Dwarf was at it funniest when they had no budget and it was a one-room comedy with occasional trips to external sets.

Answer (score -1):

He was asking Kryton about his chair because it was a metaphor about him having a 'screw loose'. He even references the screws several times. Nothing to do with Kryton using the chair as a weapon. You're welcome.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this answer?

Comment: I'll be honest, this sense as well supported as the current answer, but feels like the funnier joke so more likely to be true. Evidence would be good though.